# Python scoping in functions

Tags: python

Consider the following code:

```
>>> b = 3
>>> def change (b):
...     b = 2
... 
>>> change(b)
>>> print(b)
3
```

I am not confused by the fact that the print statement returns 3. Here's the question: is this because of scope, or because the argument that the function takes is not related to the outside `b`?

Comment: It is because of scope. Kind of too short to be an answer.

Comment: it is because of both

Comment: So is the b being used in the body of the function the same as the b I defined as 3?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/370363/2235132) might help.

Comment: It is because the *name* `b` inside is not related to the *name* `b` outside, although the values are related.  See previous questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11585768/python-how-does-passing-values-work), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/python-how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference), and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11585768/python-how-does-passing-values-work) (among others).

Comment: @goodcow: no, the `b` in `change` is a local variable. The other `b` is a *global* variable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python variable scope question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/370357/python-variable-scope-question)

Answer (score 1):

The `b` inside `change` is of a different scope than `b` outside of `change`. Inside the scope of the function, it does not matter what you call the variable before you pass it in - for now, it's going to be called `b`. As long as you don't return `b` from `change` and assign it to your "original" `b`, the first one won't change.

```
def change(b):
    b = 2
    return b

change(b)
print(b) # 3
b = change(b)
print(b) # 2
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a scoping problem. b in the function is a local variable.
globals() is dictionary which hold all global variables.

```
b=3

def change (a):
    globals()[a] = 2

print b
# 3
change("b")
print b
# 2
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question that the OP posted.

Comment: Even if you `return b`, you don't affect the global `b`.

Comment: @John Y, yes, you need to assign the new value to b.

Answer (score 0):

You are reassigning `b`. It does not change the parameter. You can test this using the `id()` function before and after the assignement.

Answer (score 0):

The scope answers are partially correct for the object type you are passing.

Check out this link for information about how python "passes by value reference"

http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/11/does-python-pass-by-value-or-by.html

Here is another link that explains pythons Local -> Enclosed -> Global -> Built-in scope resolution with some examples:

http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/rasbt/python_reference/blob/master/not_so_obvious_python_stuff.ipynb#python_legb

FWIW, the behavior is slightly different if we consider mutable objects:

```
>>> b = [3]
>>> def change(b):
...    b[0] = 2
...
>>> change(b)
>>> print(b)
[2]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have asked quite a tricky question, in the sense that the terminology you have used in framing the question is making people give you differing and weird answers.

You've given two choices:

1. we have a scope issue
2. `b` inside the function isn't related to `b` outside the function

Well, they are both true, and they are really just two ways to say the same thing.

Forgetting about terminology for a moment, realize that there is **absolutely no difference** between

```
b = 3
def f(a):
    print(a)
f(b)
```

and

```
b = 3
def f(b):
    print(b)
f(b)
```

The parameter names in a function's signature (the `def` line of a function) are local to the function, no matter what names are outside the function.

Now, you probably noticed that I sidestepped the issue of assignment within a function. That's because it's harder to explain quickly, but still be understandable and memorable to someone still in the fairly early stages of learning Python (which, no offense, it seems like you are).

Here is some reading that should help you understand fundamental concepts in Python:

- http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html
- http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/02/14/drastically-improve-your-python-understanding-pythons-execution-model/

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at [global variables](https://docs.python.org/release/2.4/ref/global.html). Just add `global b` at the beginning of your code and function, and it should work:

```
>>> global b
>>> b = 3
>>> def change():
...     global b
...     b = 2
... 
>>> b
3
>>> change()
>>> b
2
>>>
```

You also need to remove the `b` parameter from `def change(b)`, because that makes `b` both `local` and `global`. You can also [`return`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-return_stmt) `b`:

```
>>> b = 3
>>> def change(b):
...    b = 2
...    return b
...
>>> b
3
>>> b = change(b)
>>> b
2
```